# Actualizar propiedad Value/Valor de DropDownItem cargado mediante BLoC Pattern

Tags: flutter, dart

Buenas tardes compañeros, estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de una app y en ella estoy utilizando el patrón de BLoC para el proyecto.

Tengo el bloc que tiene 2 streams, uno para la lista de "holdings" y otro para el "holding seleccionado"; con la lista se carga el dropdownitem (este no tiene problemas en cargarse), y con el otro hago un sink del holding seleccionado (aquí el problema), este último lo asignado a la propiedad "value" del DropDownItem, pero me da error. En cambio si comento la propiedad "value" el combo no funciona mostrando mi opción seleccionada.

[image: DropDownItem value en blanco]

La imagen no muestra error, ya que la propiedad "value" del dropDownItem, está comentada.

Este es mi función que retorna el StreamBuilder:

```
Widget _holdingDropDown() {
return StreamBuilder(
    stream: bloc.holding,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Holding> snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.data.id);
      return Container(
        child: Center(
          child: snapshot.hasData
              ? StreamBuilder(
                  stream: bloc.obsHoldingList,
                  initialData: bloc.obsHoldingList.value,
                  builder: (BuildContext context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<List<Holding>> holdingListSnapshot) {
                    return holdingListSnapshot.hasData ?
                    DropdownButton<Holding>(
                      // value: snapshot.data,
                      items: _listDropDownHoldings,
                      onChanged: (Holding h) {
                        _changeDropDownItemHolding(h);
                      },
                    ): CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                )
              : CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      );
    });
}
```

El error que me dá es el siguiente:

> I/flutter (18314): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder>(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter (18314): _StreamBuilderBaseState, AsyncSnapshot>>#c9a1d):
>   I/flutter (18314): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 514 pos 15: 'items == null ||
>   I/flutter (18314): value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not
>   I/flutter (18314): true.

Puedo pensar que se debe a que no encuentra un item en la lista, con el valor que le estoy dando, pero no es así. No se si tenga que ver con tiempos de construcción.

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier idea que puedan darme sería de mucha ayuda.

**EDICION**

Adjunto las clases del bloc y los metodos llamados desde el StreamBuilder:

login_local_form.dart (donde se encuentra el streambuilder)

```
LoginBloc bloc;
List<DropdownMenuItem<Holding>> _listDropDownHoldings =
  new List<DropdownMenuItem<Holding>>();

void _updateDropdownListHolding(List<Holding> _holdingList) {
  _listDropDownHoldings.clear();
  _holdingList.map((h) {
    _listDropDownHoldings
        .add(new DropdownMenuItem(value: h, child: Text(h.name)));
  }).toList();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  /// Getting data from the login state container
  bloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);

  /// Loading DropdownMenuItem for holdings
  bloc.fetchAllHolding();

  /// Listener to update the holding dropdown
  bloc.obsHoldingList.listen((data) {
    _updateDropdownListHolding(data);
  });
}
```

login_bloc.dart

```
final _holding = BehaviorSubject<Holding>();
final _holdingList = PublishSubject<List<Holding>>();

Stream<Holding> get holding => _holding.stream;
ValueObservable<List<Holding>> get obsHoldingList => _holdingList.stream;

Function(Holding) get changeCurrentHolding => _holding.sink.add;

fetchAllHolding() async {
await _holdingRepository
    .fetchAllHoldings()
    .then((response) {
      _holding.sink.add(response[0]);  //  Aquí cargo el stream del hoding para el value
      _holdingList.sink.add(response);
    }, onError: (error) {
      /// If we got an error we add the error on the stream
      _holdingList.sink.addError('Error loading data!');
      print(error.toString());
    })
    .timeout(Duration(seconds: Connection.timeOutSec))
    .catchError((error) {
      /// If we got an error we add the error on the stream
      _holdingList.sink.addError(error.toString());
    })
    .whenComplete(() => print('fetchAllHolding >> Complete!!'));
}
```

**Errores**

> I/flutter ( 5949): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 5949): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder>(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter ( 5949): _StreamBuilderBaseState, AsyncSnapshot>>#7a2a6):
>   I/flutter ( 5949): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
>   I/flutter ( 5949): 
>   I/flutter ( 5949): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>   I/flutter ( 5949): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
>   I/flutter ( 5949): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
>   I/flutter ( 5949):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
>   I/flutter ( 5949): 
>   I/flutter ( 5949): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #0      WhereIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:439:11)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #1      Iterable.length (dart:core/iterable.dart:423:15)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #2      new DropdownButton (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart:514:112)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #3      _LoginLocalFormState._holdingDropDown.. (package:my_office_th_app/screens/login/login_local_form.dart:122:33)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #4      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:423:74)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #5      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:125:48)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #6      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3809:27)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:15)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #9      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3701:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3848:11)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3696:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2950:14)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2753:12)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4867:14)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #16     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #18     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3781:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2742:15)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3732:16)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3547:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #22     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2286:33)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:676:20)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #25     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #26     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #27     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #28     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): #29     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
>   I/flutter ( 5949): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 5949): Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 99676 pixels on the bottom.
>   I/flutter ( 5949): Another exception was thrown: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Comment: que tiene el método _listDropDownHoldings ?

Comment: es una lista de dropdownitems que se carga a partir del stream. Sabes lo logré resolver cargando desde el bloc, el valor inicial para la lista, pero ahora pasa algo raro, el primer stream se carga (bloc.holding) y construye, pero el segundo (bloc.obsHoldongList) no, y digo que lo logré medio resolver xq cuando abro la app solo muestra el CircularProgress pero le hago un hot reload y los muestra, parece que el 2do stream no está haciendo un callback...

Comment: depende de que haga el método _changeDropDownItemHolding

Comment: lo mejor sería si puedas proporcionar un código mínimo para poder correr y reproducir el error

Comment: en cuanto me encuentre en la pc haré una actualización de la pregunta con el bloc y los actualizadores de los stream.

Comment: he editado la pregunta con las clases y métodos vincualdos. Saludos.

Comment: quien llama a _updateDropdownListHolding ?

Comment: Lo llama el método build, mediante el bloc (edité el código adjuntando esa parte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, el error es por el tiempo de refresco de los `StreamBuilders` y como no defines un initialValue, eso causa uno de los errores (el update), el otro error es que seguro no sobreescribiste el operador == para tu clase Holding, para que se puedan comparar Objetos.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Cambiar esto:

```
final _holdingList = PublishSubject<List<Holding>>();
```

Por un BehaviorSubject :

```
final _holdingList = BehaviorSubject<List<Holding>>();
```

Y el `Observable` por un `ValueObservable` :

```
ValueObservable<List<Holding>> get obsHoldingList => _holdingList.stream;
```

Actualizas tu segundo stream con el initialData, así:

```
 StreamBuilder(
                    stream: bloc.obsHoldingList,
                    initialData: bloc.obsHoldingList.value,
```

Finalmente, sobreescribe el operador == en tu clase Holding y define que atributos quieres comparar, en este caso solo estoy usando el 'name'.

```
  class Holding {
    final String name;
    final String id;
    Holding(this.name, this.id);

    @override
    bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Holding &&
      runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
      name == other.name;

    @override
    int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
  }


void _updateDropdownListHolding(List<Holding> _holdingList) {
  _listDropDownHoldings.clear();
  _listDropDownHoldings = _holdingList
    .map((h) => DropdownMenuItem(value: h, child: Text(h.name)))
    .toList();
}
```

Comment: Listo Diego lo pruebo y te cuento, muchas gracias.

Comment: La clase ValueObservable de que libreria es? Estoy usando RxDart, y no me carga.

Comment: es de RxDart, a partir de la version 0.19.0 https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart#-changelog-tab-

Comment: Me dió un "Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null", en el _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Holding>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Holding>>>#f4bc8).

Comment: en que parte? puedes actualizar la pregunta

Comment: en _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Holding>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Holding>>>#f4bc8). Es como si el ValueObservable fuera nulo.

Comment: añade todo el error para ver en que linea es

Comment: Listo he editado la pregunta y he agregado el error.

Comment: otro cambio que hice fue el método : _updateDropdownListHolding,  puedes actualizarlo como lo puse

Comment: Nada Diego, sigo con el mismo error. Ya hice el cambio en el método que actualiza el dropdownitem. El problema es al construir el dropdownitem vdd? data hay, por que está condicionado. Por qué el bool?

Comment: a que linea de código pertenece esto : login_local_form.dart:122:33

Comment: Funcionó Diego!! pero lo hizo porque comenté los métodos que sobreescribí en la clase del holding. Ya me permite escoger y ver el cambio en el dropdown. Podrías explicarme por qué? y si no es mucha molestia, por qué utilizar value observable en vez del observable?

Comment: Al cargar los 2 streams a la vez , el último no tomaba el cambio por lo que nunca entraba, al usar un initialValue, solucionaba el problema, pero como vez, para poder obtener el último valor emitido del behaviorsubject era necesario pasar el observable al valueobservable, por eso en initialValue se usa : bloc.obsHoldingList.value    <-- ese 'value' solo lo tiene el ValueObservable.

Comment: Excelente Diego, aún me cuesta entender la diferencia entre los 3 tipos de subjects soy nuevo en programación rectiva. Si tienes un enlace que me pueda guiar te lo agradecería mucho! De todas formas gracias por el tiempo y la ayuda.

Comment: te recomiendo este supervideo de flutter y programación reactiva, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7O1UO5rEpRc